# In AspNet Boilerplate DotNetCore Console App that uses a custom AppService it does not perform the dependency injection

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am trying to make a console app that uses a custom AppService by adapting from the example https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate-samples/blob/master/AbpEfConsoleApp/AbpEfConsoleApp/Program.cs

It works for me to call the service, but when I try to use a IRepository gives me the following error

Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: 'Can't create component 'VCloud.Rtdm.CashAudit.TestManager' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.

It's as if I didn't have the IRepository registered.

Program.cs

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TestUserReferencedService();
        }
      
        /// <summary>
        /// Prueba de USAR un servicio de aspnetzero referenciando al proyecto. Spoiler: No funciona
        /// </summary>
        static async void TestUserReferencedService()
        {
            Clock.Provider = ClockProviders.Utc;
            Console.WriteLine("Starting");

            //Bootstrapping ABP system
            using (var bootstrapper = AbpBootstrapper.Create<VCloudConsoleApplicationModule>())
            {
                bootstrapper.IocManager
                    .IocContainer
                    .AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.UseAbpLog4Net().WithConfig("log4net.config"));
                bootstrapper.Initialize();

                //Getting a Tester object from DI and running it
                using (var tester = bootstrapper.IocManager.ResolveAsDisposable<TestAppService>())
                {
                    var x = (await tester.Object.TestCount());
                } //Disposes tester and all it's dependencies

                Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

VCloudConsoleApplicationModule.cs

```
 [DependsOn(
        typeof(VCloudApplicationSharedModule),
        typeof(VCloudConsoleCoreModule),
        typeof(AbpEntityFrameworkCoreModule),
        typeof(AbpDapperModule),
        typeof(AbpZeroCommonModule)
        )]
    public class VCloudConsoleApplicationModule : AbpModule
    {
        public override void PreInitialize()
        {
            //Adding authorization providers
            Configuration.Authorization.Providers.Add<AppAuthorizationProvider>();

            //Adding custom AutoMapper configuration
            Configuration.Modules.AbpAutoMapper().Configurators.Add(CustomDtoMapper.CreateMappings);
            Configuration.BackgroundJobs.IsJobExecutionEnabled = false;
        }

        public override void Initialize()
        {
            IocManager.RegisterAssemblyByConvention(typeof(VCloudConsoleApplicationModule).GetAssembly());
            DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SetMappingAssemblies(new List<Assembly>
                {typeof(VCloudConsoleApplicationModule).GetAssembly()});
            DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.SetMappingAssemblies(new List<Assembly>
            {
                typeof(VCloud.Dapper.Mappers.DapperMapper_RtdmOrder).GetAssembly(),
                typeof(VCloud.Dapper.Mappers.DapperMapper_RtdmOrderItem).GetAssembly(),
                typeof(VCloud.Dapper.Mappers.DapperMapper_RtdmCompany).GetAssembly(),
                typeof(VCloud.Dapper.Mappers.DapperMapper_RtdmRestaurant).GetAssembly()
            });
            //DapperExtensions.DapperExtensions.Configure();
            //Dapper.DefaultTypeMap.MatchNamesWithUnderscores = true;
        }
    }
```

TestManager.cs

```
    public class TestManager : VCloudDomainServiceBase, ITestManager
    {
        private IRepository<Invoice> _repository;

        public TestManager(IRepository<Invoice> repository)
        {
            _repository = repository;
        }

        public async Task<int> GetCount()
        {
            return await _repository.CountAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to Dependeny Injection, the problem may be you forget to add the entity `Invoice` to the `DbContext` of your application in EntityFramework project.

Once you add it your problem will be solved.

```
public class VCloudApplicationDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User, VCloudApplicationDbContext>, IAbpPersistedGrantDbContext
{
    public DbSet<Invoice> Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

I hope it could help you

Comment: Can I contact you?
I'm still having problems with this project and I could use your help, as a freelance paid job. If you are interested, look for my full name on Linkedin